# How to find Beta?

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataframe (of prices) as given below

```
dat <- data.frame(company = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "index"), each = 5),
prices = c(runif(5, 10, 12), runif(5, 108, 112), runif(5, 500, 510),
runif(5, 40, 50), runif(5, 1000, 1020)))
```

I need to find the beta
of A, B, C and D w.r.t index.

Beta between two variables X and Y (where Y is dependent) is given by

```
beta <- coef(lm(Y ~ X))[2]
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is the outcome in your specific example? Price? And what do you mean by "w.r.t. index"?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a comment but it is too long.  It looks like your basic data management problem is restructuring the data from long to wide format.  See below for one way to do that.

Once you've done that however you will have a problem that your data is so small.  If I understand your data correctly, you have five observations each of five variables (four companies and one index) and you are interested in the relationship of the prices of the four companies to the index.  If you a fit a model with all four company prices as explanatory variables your model is fully saturated and you cannot perform any inference - in the same way as fitting a regression line to just two two-variable points your line is guaranteed to be a perfect fit through both points, in your case your four dimensional hyper-plane is guaranteed to pass through your five points.

```
> dat <- data.frame(company = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "index"), each = 5),
+                   prices = c(runif(5, 10, 12), runif(5, 108, 112), runif(5, 500, 510),
+                              runif(5, 40, 50), runif(5, 1000, 1020)))
> library(reshape2)
> 
> dat$period <- rep(1:5, 5)

> 
> 
> dat.w <- reshape(dat, direction="wide",timevar="period", idvar="company")
> dat.w2 <- as.data.frame(t(dat.w[,-1]))
> names(dat.w2) <- dat.w$company
> dat.w2
                A        B        C        D    index
prices.1 10.02256 111.9359 504.0302 41.76821 1011.407
prices.2 10.91205 111.7201 509.5110 42.02183 1009.466
prices.3 11.99433 110.2322 507.7807 49.02281 1003.605
prices.4 11.80242 111.5317 502.2366 43.82982 1013.080
prices.5 11.21026 110.7937 508.8268 42.12567 1015.396
> 
> pairs(dat.w2)
```

[image]

```
> 
> summary(lm(index~A+B+C+D, data=dat.w2))

Call:
lm(formula = index ~ A + B + C + D, data = dat.w2)

Residuals:
ALL 5 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 2095.5333         NA      NA       NA
A              1.7965         NA      NA       NA
B             -5.5467         NA      NA       NA
C             -0.7494         NA      NA       NA
D             -2.4789         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:     1,  Adjusted R-squared:   NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 4 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA 

> summary(lm(index~A, data=dat.w2))

Call:
lm(formula = index ~ A, data = dat.w2)

Residuals:
prices.1 prices.2 prices.3 prices.4 prices.5 
  -1.379   -1.645   -5.468    3.646    4.846 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1031.661     34.823  29.626 8.45e-05 ***
A             -1.883      3.106  -0.606    0.587    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 4.875 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.1091, Adjusted R-squared: -0.1878 
F-statistic: 0.3676 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.5871
```